# IE11 print commant popup doesnt have the vertical scroll bar not visible while it is visible in chrome

Tags: java, html, css

CSS code :

```
DIV.ScrollBoxSR 
{

height:225px;
border-top: 2px inset silver;
border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
border-right: 2px inset silver;
border-left: 2px inset silver;
overflow-x: `hidden` !important;
overflow-y: auto !important;
white-space: normal;
word-break: break-all; 
word-wrap: break-word;

}


HTML code:

       <div class="ScrollBoxSR" id="srscroller">


               <table class="ADVScalar" width="100%">
              <tr><td>
                 <vstext vspreservetag="true" name="GEN_PRNTSR_HTML" vsds=" ">
                 </td></tr>
                </table>

       </div>
```

the problem is that the on the click of the print button on this html page the popup has no vertical scroll bar and that is a requirement. i have shared the code kindly let me know what changes are required and it is visible in chrome and firefox. Problem presists only in IE11

```
        <td><div>
                 <input class="ADVButton" type="submit" id="AMSDocPrintLink" title="Print Document"  name="AMSDocPrintLink" vsds="" href="VSS" value="Print" vsds="" vsaction=""
                 onclick="printSRResponse()">&nbsp;
        </div></td>
        <td><div>


function printSRResponse()
{
   var loSRPrintWin=window.open();
   loSRPrintWin.document.write(document.getElementById('srscroller').innerHTML);
   loSRPrintWin.window.location.reload();
   loSRPrintWin.focus();
   loSRPrintWin.print();
   loSRPrintWin.close;
   event.returnValue=false;
   return false;
}
```